# GridView Paging Not Working When Page Is Called via Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I am working with asp.net page which calls another ASPX page containing GridView with paging inside update panel

I call the page via jquery and its loading fine but when I click on Gridview paging, the Grid view disappears

```
<div id = "divParent">

</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   BindDiv('divParent', 'Parent.aspx');         
});

function BindDiv(DivID, url) {
        $('#' + DivID).empty();
        $('#' + DivID).append('<img src="Images/ajax_loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />');

        $.get(url, function (response) {
            $('#' + DivID).empty();
            $('#' + DivID).append($(response).find('#ParentContainer')); 

        });
    }
```

second aspx page code

```
<div id = "ParentContainer">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers ="true" UpdateMode ="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvParent" runat="server" SkinID="gvParent" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="gvParent_PageIndexChanging">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer ID" SortExpression="CustomerID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="Fname">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

plz help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mix up everything.
Understand what each part do here and you understand why this can not work.

`Parent.aspx` page that hold the GridView and also have inside her the UpdatePanel need to make post back to the same page and get return from the same page to work.

The other page that have the jQuery and load the `Parent.aspx` is get the results, rendered it to a different page and the javascript that `Parent.aspx` contains never run. Now the full code of the `Parent.aspx` is inside some other page and you try to make an ajax call to the `Parent.aspx` again, and get results where ?

The grid view is an "out of the box" control that need some standard way to correctly work. The UpdatePanel have been design that can hold the GridView and they can work together because they have been design that way.

If you add jQuery load, then you need to make all that logic custom, to make your custom grid view, your custom calls etc.

If you mix them up, they simple not work.

Comment: Actually default.aspx page calls parent.aspx which contains gridview  inside update panel and all the jquery stuff and divParent is in default.aspx and is loading fine but gridview paging is not working

Comment: @KamranAkhter Use ether MasterPage to connect your data together, or in the worst case, use iframe to load the parent.aspx - in the case of iframe you do not need the UpdatePanel.

Comment: Thanks for reply, default.aspx and parent.aspx both connected to master page

Comment: Actually the goal is to load multiple grids one by one with animation, second grid should be start loading when first grid rendered completely and i have achieved this but gridview paging not working

Comment: @KamranAkhter Ok, I understand, but you can not mix up jQuery ajax call with GridView and wait the rest of gridview to work. Nether can make ajax call to a page that all ready use ajax (UpdatePanel). Understand that the ajax call is getting just data, is not keep the rest functionality of the page that is needed for complex works, like paging, editing, deleting etc.

Comment: OK thanks, Can u advice me that what should I do to achieve the animation goal

Comment: @KamranAkhter Use iframes, or some kind of javascript that load the one UpdatePanel after the other.

Comment: one more thing to share i have created another page with child.aspx page and calls it to the same way but the difference is, child.aspx page not connected with master page and have a form inside the page it loads the grid and paging it first time correctly but clicking on paging no 3 it is giving viewstate error